# elasticsearch exceeds memory after few hours

Tags: elasticsearch

In our system, 5000-15000 records written to elasticsearch(1.7.3) per minute, for first 4-5 hours its fine but after then it starts slowing down and almost no response any read or write request. After we restart elastic service its works fine for 4-5 hours again..

When elasticsearch starts slowing I checked the memory its about %95 so I think this is the reason why its broken but I dont understand why its loading RAM and never flush it.. No point of increasing ram, We have 8 GB RAM and elastic reached %95 of it in 5 hours..

Is there anything handle this? flush memory or auto restart elastic etc. ?

**EDITED**

Here is sample document in index:

```
"hits": {
      "total": 18083446,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "userlogs",
            "_type": "userlogstype",
            "_id": "AVMZEEYwW1W7iq27fTcE",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "domain": "http://gatr.hit.gemius.pl/",
               "url": "http://gatr.hit.gemius.pl/_1456414408406/rexdot.js?",
               "filetype": "-",
               "clientname": "NOTINDOMAIN",
               "clientmac": "00:0c:29:8f:c4:4f",
               "hierarchycode": "HIER_DIRECT/188.165.145.88",
               "user": "-",
               "duration": "168",
               "respsize": "1059",
               "clientip": "10.6.1.130",
               "loggingdate": "25/02/2016 17:33:28",
               "resultcode": "TCP_MISS/301",
               "reqmethod": "GET"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "userlogs",
            "_type": "userlogstype",
            "_id": "AVMZEEYwW1W7iq27fTcI",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "domain": "http://10.6.2.212/",
```

and here is mapping of index:

```
{
   "webproxylog": {
      "mappings": {
         "update_by_query": {
            "properties": {
               "query": {
                  "properties": {
                     "filtered": {
                        "properties": {
                           "filter": {
                              "properties": {
                                 "term": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "url": {
                                          "type": "string"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "script": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         },
         "accesslog": {
            "properties": {
               "action": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "action4cat": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "category": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "clientip": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "clientmac": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "clientname": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "domain": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "duration": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "filetype": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "hierarchycode": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "index": {
                  "properties": {
                     "_index": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "_type": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "loggingdate": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
               },
               "reqmethod": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "respsize": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "resultcode": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "url": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "user": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

query sample :

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "instock"
              }
            },
            {}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "aggs1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "clientname",
        "size": 5,
        "order": {
          "aggs2": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "aggs2": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "respsize"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a "few" more questions for starters (please update your question with your responses): 1) What version of ES are you running? 2) Can you show us a sample document you're indexing + eventually the mapping type you're using? 3) How many documents in total do you have? 4) Are queries being served at the same time you're loading data into ES?

Comment: and yes.. application also serving documents during indexing. So get request simultaneously with indexing

Comment: Then can you also share a few queries you're serving? Are you using aggregations, sorting, eventually scripting? How many total documents do you have? And which ES version?

Comment: I already edited post including answers. and added simple aggregation query frequently used.. But the thing here is not query I think because I never change the dsl queries at first its perfect : 10 milisecond avg. response time.. after 5 hours 20-30 second.. and memory of server %95

Comment: What are the empty must clauses in your query? And do you confirm you have around 20M docs in your index?

Comment: its optinal parameters defined by user in gui, this query is the first to post elastichsearch on pageload, I refresh page, copy the dsl there. now its too quick elastic responses 10-15 milisecond because I restart service :D but before than when I refresh page it takes too long because elastic was too slow to response (I view simple dashboard filled by data in elasticsearch )

Comment: The next time you run ouf of memory, can you run run these two commands and paste the output into your question: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/fielddata` and `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/stats`. That will give us some more insights into what is consuming memory. Thanks

Comment: I advise you to read this documentation : [elasticsearch doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/_limiting_memory_usage.html)

Comment: @Erms I am reading now, thank you.

Comment: It's most certainly a fielddata issue, which you'll need to limit, but we'll know soon